# Append array value to string

Tags: javascript

How can an array value (could be any number less than 20K) be appended to a string?
I'm trying to imitate :

> if (form1.EActQ2**0** === undefined) { Q2B**0** = 0; }
>       else (Q2B**0** = document.form1.EActQ2**0**.value);

```
var und = x < 20000;
var less1 = form1.EActQ1.und.toString();
var less2 = form1.EActQ2.und.toString();
var less3 = form1.EActQ3.und.toString();
var less4 = form1.EActQ4.und.toString();

if (less1 === undefined) { Q1B.und.toString() = 0; }
else (Q1B.und.toString() = document.less1.value); /// is now a value to get added in  an equation

if (less2 === undefined) { Q2B.und.toString() = 0; }
else (Q2B.und.toString() = document.less2.value);

if (less3 === undefined) { Q3B.und.toString() = 0; }
else (Q3B.und.toString() = document.less3.value);

if (less4 === undefined) { Q4B.und.toString() = 0; }
else (Q4B.und.toString() = document.less4.value);
```

***/// Revised Code Below***

```
arr = [];
var und = 0; // some number below 2000
var less = form1["EActQ1" + und];

if (less1 === undefined) {
  arr[und] = 0;
} else {
  arr[und] = document["less1" + und].value;
}

if (less2 === undefined) {
  arr[und] = 0;
} else {
  arr[und] = document["less2" + und].value;
}

if (less3 === undefined) {
  arr[und] = 0;
} else {
  arr[und] = document["less3" + und].value;
}

if (less1 === undefined) {
  arr[und] = 0;
} else {
  arr[und] = document["less1" + und].value;
}



add =  (["Q1B"+ und] * 1)+(["Q2B"+ und] * 1)+(["Q3B"+ und] * 1)+(["Q4B"+ und] * 1);
```

Returns NaN. I'm defining cells based on their values and trying to add them up.

Comment: What values do these properties have? I don't know anything whose `.toString()` method returns `undefined`. And your code doesn't really make sense - you can't assign to the result of a call.

Comment: To string was an attempt to force my variable to read as a number appended to text. All of this is to check if any (cell) value is defined

Comment: The following doesn't make much sense, can you explain what it is you are trying to do here? `Q1B.und.toString() = document.less1.value`

Comment: If a value in cell is undefined, then that cell value is the equivalent of zero, else the value given should be used. I'm defining each cell by it's array value - which is provided by php/html form in a dynamic row table. I don't want to have to write a new javascript line for every new row. I need javascript for functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
var und = 0; // some number below 2000
var less = form1["EActQ" + und];
```

Also use an object to collect all those values, not a set of `Q2B…` variables. Or even better, just an array:

```
arr = [];
…
if (less === undefined) {
  arr[und] = 0;
} else {
  arr[und] = document["less" + und].value;
}
```

Comment: javascript expects an identifier, instead of bracket notation.Can you fix with the "object" example?

Comment: How do I capture each quarter? Q1-4

Comment: Include the quarter in the property name (obj.Q1B1), use four arrays (Q1[1]) or make an array of the four quarters (arr[1][1]). I don't know what your task is, so I can't recommend the appropriate data structure. In any case, bracket notation will always work the same, with string concatenation or without.

Comment: Bracket notation works only for properties in objects (or arrays). The `["Q1B"+ und]` in your code is an array literal. I recommend to first write out your code in complete detail, with hardcoded property names, and get it working so that you have an idea how the objects you want to create should look. Then try to abstract from that with dynamic property names and loops, if there are problems with that you can ask us for help but please post the working non-generalised code with it.